# How to build entities of a House

Tags: aframe

I have a web application that allow user can customize their house. Now i just use several small pics and display over the base pic (full house).

I want to use A-Frame to build entities of a house to improve performance and also provide VR experience for user. How can I build entities of a house such as roof, wall, door using A-Frame ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at the room component. It allows you to make rooms and doorways through the a-frame DOM structure.

More details at the github page below.

https://github.com/omgitsraven/aframe-room-component